# DataGridView, add TextBox below each column header

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to make a filtering system for DataGridView. TextBoxes outside DataGridView are not enought, I need to put them inside DataGridView. Is this possible? I know it's possible to make custom cell control, but is this possible with header?

Comment: I'm forced to use DataTable. dataGridView.Source = dataTable;

Comment: So you want to create  ONE row below the headers, in which you'll enter your filter?

Comment: Imagine I have grid with 3 columns (headers): name, surname, age. Now I need some 1 extra row, uder these headers, to insert 3x TextBox. When I will type something in these textboixes, filter should be applied.

Comment: Is there no possibility to use DataView?

Comment: Maybe I can. Whats the difference? Im talking about GUI. For now I achieved something like this: Add bottom border to header (because setting Height of header didnt work). Now I have free space for text box. Now i create textBox with parent datagridview1. Now i can move text box to specified location. I just getting cell (0,0) location, and just move textbox a little bit up. IF you have better solution, please explain me.

Comment: Look into GlacialList control. it's s list where you can add custom controls wherever your want in it. If you want ONLY Row 6 col 8 to have a datepicker you can. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4012/C-List-View-v1-3 Note that glacial list is version 1.3. there is more recent version bu 1.3 is free because the guy made it before he created Glacial Control company that offer much more controls

Comment: Thanks. I cannot use any oper-source code etc. I think i solved my problem with creating TextBox with parent on dataGridView1 and control on resize/columnWidth events etc.